# Ошибка System.Security.SecurityException: "Requested registry access is not allowed." в UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, реестр

Я делаю программу на c#. И мне нужно было создать раздел в реестре и параметр Dword в нем. Мне нужна была ветка HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. В общем я написал этот код:

```
RegistryKey LcMach = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey key = LcMach.OpenSubKey(@"System\ControlSet001\Control\", true);
key.CreateSubKey(@"BootControl\");
key.SetValue("BootProgressAnimation", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

И так получилось, что возникла проблема:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: "Requested registry access is not allowed."
```

Пошелестев интернет, я искал решение проблемы. Выяснив, что код не работает без прав администратора, я добавил в app.manifest этот код:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

После этого возникла та же история. Запускал Visual Studio от имени администратора - без толку.
Еще 1 код попробовал, но и это меня не спасало:

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
using (var regkey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"System\ControlSet001\Control\", writable: true))
{
    var reg = regkey.CreateSubKey(@"BootControl\", writable:true);
    reg.SetValue("BootProgressAnimation", 1);
}
```

И так обрыскав весь интернет, я пришел сюда. В чем проблема неработоспособности этого кода?

***НОВЫЕ ПОДРОБНОСТИ:***
Я только что попробовал использовать этот код в WPF и UWP. В WPF все сработало. Но с UWP другая ситуация. Не понятно почему в UWP, если прописать `using Microsoft.Win32;`, то возникает ошибка, что нет в этом классе RegestryKey. Если не прописывать этого, то если нажать на правую кнопку мыши на RegestryKey, то в меню написано не импортировать `using Microsoft.Win32;`, а написано скачать (или найти) и установить Microsoft.Win32 через NuGet.

Comment: 1) приложение должно быть собрано как x64 (не Any CPU). 2) должно быть запущено с правами администратора, чтобы иметь доступ в HKLM ветку.

Comment: 1) оно с самого начала было собрано как x64. 2) вопрос: мне из самого visual studio запускать код как админ? Или же в свойствах самого кода поставить галку, чтоб запускалось от админа, и оно автоматом как админ открывалось в VS?

Comment: VS надо запустить от админа, хотя если вы в манифесте правильно прописали требование админа, студия должна сама предложить перезапуститься от админа

Comment: Прикол в том, что я запускал и от админа, и как обычно, но студия ничего мне не предлагала. И постоянно возникала эта ошибка, хотя я в манифесте только 1 строку менял, ту, которая отвечает за админку моей проги

Comment: А руками через редактор реестра это получается сделать?

Comment: Да, получается.

Comment: Эта проблема касается именно всей ветки HKLM, я абсолютно ничего сделать не могу. Только руками если отредачить что-то в этой ветке .

Comment: Я тут еще раз протестил этот код уже на других видах программ (WPF и UWP) и тут кое-что выясняется. Я уже отредактировал вопрос и описание, можно посмотреть

Comment: UWP - не Win32 приложение, а WinRT. Там нет доступа к Win32 API, вы не можете редактировать реекстр как в WPF. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48900974/12888024 _If your app is a pure UWP app, this is not possible_

Comment: Я уже почитал про это, и уже нашел свой обход этого ограничения

Comment: Завтра или послезавтра напишу как решить эту проблему

Comment: Обратите внимание на новый проект Microsoft - Windows App SDK (WinUI 3). Он объединяет UWP и Win32. Выйдет в релиз 12 ноября, или около того. Требует Win10 + .NET 6, так что если вам это подходит, рекомендую сразу изучить, что к чему. Ну и там новый интерфейс.

Comment: Я сейчас использую библиотеку WinUi 2.6 с новым интерфейсом Windows 11, а так если есть уже 3 варианта решения (до которых я додумался) моей проблемы зачем ждать? А так пока что WinUi 3 я не пользуюсь из-за того, что я никак не могу посмотреть как выглядит моя прога.

Comment: `никак не могу посмотреть как выглядит моя прога` можно попробовать запустить ее :)

Comment: Это понятное дело, но конструктор отсутствует, что для меня не очень хорошо

Comment: Крч, есть еще 1 прикол я создал консольное приложение (с правами админа и тем кодом, связанным с реестром.) Он отлично запускается отдельно. В моей основной проге, когда я запускаю через `Process.Start();` и `using (System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process()) //и др`, то моя основная прога **находит тот код**, запускает, закрывает. Все бы ничего, но код, который он нашел не выполняется. С расположением все в порядке. Почему так работает?

Comment: Если бы WinRT защиту было бы так просто объехать, то это была бы не защита. Вы не можете классическим образом запустить Win32 приложение из UWP приложения. `Process.Start` не прокатит, но есть конечно `FullTrustProcessLauncher`, можете его поизучать.

Comment: Тогда через часика 3 попробую

Comment: Вроде бы все импортировал для FullTrustProcessLauncher, но в строке `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();` вызывается исключение `System.Exception: "Такой запрос не поддерживается. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)"
`

Comment: В общем ничего дельного не нашел по этой ошибке, видимо придется ждать или переписывать, но уже на wpf